# Refactor Firebase API

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, refactoring

I have the following source code structure:

```
src
|__ api
|__|___ config.js
|__|___ index.js
```

Index file is pretty big with more than 20 async calls:

The index.js as below:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './config';

class FireBase {
    constructor() {
        if (firebase.apps.length === 0) { firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); }
        this.firebase = firebase;
        this.firestore = this.firebase.firestore();
        this.auth = this.firebase.auth();
    }
    auth() {
        return this.auth;
    }
    *******************************************
    async login(email, password)
    async logout()
    async resetPassword(password)
    async onAuthStateChanged(cb)
    *******************************************        
    async fetchSettings()
    async fetchUserData(userId)
    async updateSettings(data)
    *******************************************
    async getRecord(collection, id)
    async updateRecord(collection, id, data)
    async createRecord(collection, _data)
    async deleteRecord(collection, id)
    async saveRecordWithId(collection, id, data) 
    async findAllRecords(collection)
    *******************************************
    async saveProduct(data, id)
    async saveCategory(data, id)
    async saveCategoryProduct(data, id)
    async saveCart(data, id)
    .................


}

const Api = new FireBase();
export default Api;
```

I want to split several calls to smaller file inside api folder. For example, with login/logout/reset, I want to move to auth.js; fetchSettings/updateSettings move to settings.js, crud records move to records.js. Then I will import these files into the inde.js file. However, all the async calls above belong to larger class Firebase, then we will have to create instant of the class and export that instance. How should I do now?